# How to get the json object from servlet and how to use the object to render it in ext js grid panel

Tags: jsp, servlets, extjs

I have my Json object from servlet:

```
myObj.put("BatchStatusTracker", arrayObj);
```

My root is : BatchStatusTracker
My json data array is : arrayObj

```
sample data output: 
{"BatchStatusTracker":[{"clientId":"WMD","createdDate":"14-MAR-2018","eventName":"DAILY_BATCH","startTime":"00:04","endTime":"04:32","runTime":"4 Hr : 28 Mins","status":"SUCCESS"}]}
```

Here is my jsp page: Test_table.jsp

```
Ext.onReady(function() {        
                var reader = new Ext.data.JsonReader(
                {root : "myObj"},
                bst);

                var bst = Ext.data.Record.create([
                { name: 'clientId'}, { name: 'createdDate'}, { name: 'eventName'}, { name: 'startTime'}, { name: 'endTime'}, { name: 'runTime'}, { name: 'status'}
                ]);

                var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({           
                reader : reader,               
                proxy:{
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url : 'FetchingUserDetails'
                    }

                });
                var grid1 = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                    store: store,
                    cm: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
                            {header : 'Client',dataIndex : 'clientId',flex : 5},
                            {header : 'Date',dataIndex : 'createdDate',flex : 5},
                            {header : 'Event Name',dataIndex : 'eventName',flex : 5},
                            {header : 'Start Time',dataIndex : 'startTime',flex : 5},
                            {header : 'End Time',dataIndex : 'endTime',flex : 5},
                            {header : 'Run Time',dataIndex : 'runTime',flex : 5},
                            {header : 'Status',dataIndex : 'status',    flex : 5}
                    ]),
                    title: 'Batch Status Tracker',
                    renderTo: document.body
                    });

                    store.load();


    });
```

When the run the jsp page with Apache tomcat. The page runs and it calling servlet( I have verified by using syso(syso output: Entered servlet). I am seeing my grid with title, but data is not showing up. Please help me out.  I have analysed many links,i am not getting any proper answer. If possible show me some example for this scenario. Thank in advance

Comment: which extjs version is this ?

Answer (score 1):

Reader's root property is wrong should be BatchStatusTracker not myObj

```
 var reader = new Ext.data.JsonReader(
                {root : "BatchStatusTracker"},
                bst);
```